# How to detect '\n\r' with FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader

I'm loading a file  on my webapp and I use this function I found on a website to read it:

```
<script>        
    function readBlob() {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;

        if (!files.length) {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var start = 0;
        var stop = file.size - 1;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
            }
        };

        var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);

        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

    }                                     
</script>
```

The reading works fine but it seems that the `"\n\r"` is not read and all my lines are stick together.
Is there anything to change in this code to take account of `'\n\r'` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
`#byte_content { white-space: pre}`

Comment: As a note, new lines in windows are `\r\n`, not `\n\r`. In Linux, it is just `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with CSS only. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCfZK/). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```
#byte_content { white-space: pre}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job, I asked for JavaScript solution, but if it can be done in CSS, that's ok.